# Guardar PDF en un directorio C#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes a todos, buscando de su apoyo para poder guardar un archivo PDF en un directorio seleccionado, cuento con el siguiente metodo en el cual ya puedo ver los directorios y seleccionar el archivo, si alguién puede decirme como resolverlo, de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SaveFileDialog objSave = new SaveFileDialog();
        objSave.Filter = "Archivos de texto (*.pdf)|*.pdf|Todos los archivos (*.*)|*.*";               
        objSave.Title = "Seleccione un PDF";
        objSave.ShowDialog();
        if (objSave.FileName != "")
        {
            System.IO.FileStream file = (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.btnGuardar.
                    //this.btnGuardar.Image.Save(file,
                    //   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es el problema?

Comment: No se guarda el archivo por que las lineas comentadas solo sirven para guardar imagenes y necesito guardar archivos PDF.